# Update Manger offline error

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, using the i3 window manager.
I'm having troubles with the Software and Updates for my system. 
When I start the `update-manager` I get this screen :

[image: 1_internet fail]

The internet is working when I see this, I'm not using a proxy.

---

After selecting `ok` (bottom right) I see this :

[image: Ubuntu_base_update]

I select `install now` (from the bottom right) which just closes the screen. I
then run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y` just for measure, and
then restart the computer. This has made no difference.

---

[image: Ubuntu Software]

I can't select any of those radio buttons, or at least if I do select one it
doesn't stay selected.

---

Starting from the left (Ubuntu Software) this is what I have, I can't select
any of the radio buttons that are on these pages:

[image: Ubuntu Software]

[image: Other software]

[image: Updates]

[image: Authentication]

[image: Additional drivers]

After selecting 'close' on the previous window I SOMETIMES the following message :

[image: Information about available software]

After pressing reload on that I get this error message (again, my network is fine while I'm getting this)

[image: Fail to download repo]

Here is the error message text from that :

```
W:GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease: The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY 54422A4B98AB5139, W:Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been
ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After closing that screen I get the update manager which displays the following:

[image: Update available]

I'm not sure why these are an option when the others weren't.

I have displayed pictures of the GUI because I'm not sure how this ties in to the apt-get and such, but I'm happy to utilise any CLI methods.

## Edit

Here's the output of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse restricted main #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse restricted main

deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

Output of `apt-get update`

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Get:1 http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease [5,637 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en
Fetched 5,637 B in 2s (2,360 B/s)
```

### edit

I'm not sure what I'm meant to do about this error - `apt-cdrom` ?

```
W:GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54422A4B98AB5139, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty
```

### edit 2

I've logged in with Unity instead of i3 which has enabled me to install a few
things using the update manager, as well as alter the option of Universe
packages (because it prompted for a password whereas this didn't happen on i3,
so the privileges weren't correct).

However I still get the `Check you internet connection` error when I load the
Update manager (from within Unity).

Here's an error that I got after trying to `reload` the package information from
the update manager :

```
W:GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54422A4B98AB5139, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

All the sources are commented out. Remove the "#" in front of the entries starting with "deb" in your sources.list.

Comment: after uncommenting those the same behaviour is happening. I'm going to do a system restart and see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: did you do a "sudo apt-get update & upgrade" ?

Comment: yeah, still has the same 'failed to download...'